# how to use grid positioning in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am new to pyqt. I am trying to built a program using QtGui.QMainWindow.

First: is it true that I can't use grid to place object in the parent?

Second: if it is possible , how can I use it?

More specifically, I want to use grid to place widgets in a window which has menu bar.

Comment: This question is too broad. Any introduction into PyQt will give you an answer eventually.

Answer (score -1):

> *First: is it true that I can't use grid to place object in the parent?*

*EEEEw* it's false!

> *Second: if it is possible , how can I use it?*

here it goes: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/

> - The most universal layout class is the grid layout. This layout divides the space into rows and columns. To create a grid layout, we use the QtGui.QGridLayout class.

there's even a nice image:

[image: grid layout]

I'm not giving code here, just read the tutorial!

in other, fine words: **RTFM!** ;-)